# python manipulating files, logic error in script?

Tags: python, loops, coordinates, file-manipulation

I have a file that looks like this:

**Chr-coordinate-coverage**

```
chr1    236968289   2
chr1    236968318   2
chr1    236968320   2
chr1    236968374   2
chr1    237005709   2
chr14   22086843    2
chr14   22086846    2
chr14   22086849    2
chr14   22086851    4
chr2    5078129 2
chr2    5341758 2
chr2    5342443 2
```

I want to manipulate it to obtain:

**chr-start-end-average coverage-distance**

```
chr1  236968289  236968374 2    85    
chr14 22086843   22086851  2.5  8
chr2  5078129    5078129   2    0
chr2  5341758    5342443   2    685
```

I want that:
if chr is different from the previous chr **or** the difference between coordinates is bigger then 1000: it prints the output as shown. With the chr, the starting coordinate, the ending coordinate, the average coverage and the distance between start and end.

To do so, I wrote the following code:

```
cov=open("coverage.txt")
oldchr="chr55"      #dummy starting data
oldcoordinate=1
sumcoverage=0
startcoordinate=0

try:
   while True:
    line=next(cov).split("\t",2)
    newchr=line[0]
    newcoordinate=int(line[1])       #read informations from file
    newcoverage=int(line[2].strip())

    if oldchr != newchr or newcoordinate - oldcoordinate > 1000:
        distance=oldcoordinate-startcoordinate
        averagecoverage=sumcoverage/distance
        merge=oldchr+'\t'+str(startcoordinate)+'\t'+str(oldcoordinate)+'\t'+str(averagecoverage)+'\t'+str(distance) 
        print merge
        startcoordinate=newcoordinate
        sumcoverage=0

    oldchr=newchr
    oldcoordinate=newcoordinate     #replace old with new chr and coordinates
    sumcoverage=sumcoverage+newcoverage


except(StopIteration):
    print ""
```

I am not able to understand why it doesn't work properly.
The error I got is that the division to obtain the "average coverage" is trying to divide per 0, so in many cases the "distance" (          **distance=oldcoordinate-startcoordinate**) is equal to 0.
This should not happen, in the input file is never the case that 2 lines have the same coordinate. I am not able to see where the error is.
I hope someone can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Check that each time you are correctly reading the next line. And check that `newcoordinate` is updated correctly.

Comment: I checked, line and new coordinate are read correctly from the file at the beginning of every clycle

Comment: Inside the if you call `startcoordinate=newcoordinate`  then outside the if you call `oldcoordinate=newcoordinate`. So `startcoordinate == oldcoordinate`.  In the next iteration you are only updating `newcoordinate` but the distance is defined as `distance=oldcoordinate-startcoordinate` which will be 0.

Comment: I added an if distance== 0 : act differently. It is better now, still not exactly the result I want, but better, I guess there is something else wrong in the logic

Comment: The value `237005709` seems to have vanished from your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function to group up your entries according to the `chr` column. The [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) library also makes it easier to process the file:

```
from itertools import groupby
import csv

def display_block(block):
    average_coverage = sum(x[2] for x in block) / float(len(block))
    print block[0][0], "\t", block[0][1], "\t", block[-1][1], "\t", average_coverage, "\t", block[-1][1] - block[0][1]


with open('coverage.txt', 'rb') as f_coverage:
    for chr, entries in groupby(csv.reader(f_coverage, delimiter='\t'), lambda x: x[0]):
        entries = [(e[0], int(e[1]) , int(e[2])) for e in entries]
        block = []
        ientries = iter(entries)
        block.append(next(ientries))

        for chr, coord, coverage in ientries:
            if coord - block[-1][1] > 1000:
                display_block(block)
                block = []
            block.append([chr, coord, coverage])

        if len(block):
            display_block(block)
```

This would display the following output:

```
chr1    236968289   236968374   2.0     85
chr1    237005709   237005709   2.0     0
chr14   22086843    22086851    2.5     8
chr2    5078129     5078129     2.0     0
chr2    5341758     5342443     2.0     685
```

Each iteration of the `for` loop gives you a current `chr` and all matching rows for that `chr`. The script goes through each row and converts the `coord` and `coverage` to integers. It then makes the list it into an iterator. The first matching row is stored in `block` and then any remaining rows are iterated over. Each time the distance is greater than `1000` the block is displayed and restarted. Any remaining entries at the end are then also displayed.

Tested using Python 2.7.6